# Postgres: Sum from multiple joins resulting in values being more than expected

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

I have 3 tables: **invoices, invoice_payments, invoice_credit_notes**. I want to fetch all those invoices where the total paid amount is less than the `grand_total` amount in invoices table.

In invoice model

```
has_many :invoice_payments
has_many :invoice_credit_notes
```

In invoice_payments model

```
belongs_to :invoice
```

In invoice_credit_notes model

```
belongs_to :invoice
```

`invoice_payments` has `amount` and `discount` field in it.

`invoice_credit_notes` has `amount` field in it.

Here's what I came up with:

```
scope :unpaid, ->{left_outer_joins(:invoice_payments, :credit_note_invoices)
                  .having('(COALESCE(SUM(invoice_payments.amount + invoice_payments.discount), 0) + COALESCE(SUM(credit_note_invoices.amount), 0)) < ROUND(invoices.grand_total, 0)')
                  .group('invoices.id')}
```

But there's an issue with my solution as there can be multiple invoice_payments or invoice_credit_notes the `(COALESCE(SUM(invoice_payments.amount + invoice_payments.discount), 0) + COALESCE(SUM(invoice_credit_notes.amount), 0)` is returning an amount that is higher than the actual paid amount. This is most probably because multiple tables are being joined.

So, how to overcome this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The statement generates this (simplified) query:

```
select sum(p.amount+ p.discount)+ sum(n.amount)
from invoice i
left join invoice_payments p on p.invoice_id = i.id
left join invoice_credit_notes n on n.invoice_id = i.id
group by i.id;
```

The two joins create the Cartesian product of all rows from `invoice_payments` and `invoice_credit_notes` with the same `invoice_id` so `amounts` are summed multiple times. You should calculate the aggregates in separate derived tables (subqueries):

```
select p.sum+ n.sum
from invoice i
left join (
    select invoice_id, sum(amount+ discount)
    from invoice_payments
    group by invoice_id
    ) p on p.invoice_id = i.id
left join (
    select invoice_id, sum(amount)
    from invoice_credit_notes
    group by invoice_id
    ) n on n.invoice_id = i.id
```

I hope you can easily translate this to ruby.

Comment: This will not work if the database requires full groups. You will need to group by invoice_id, amount, discount

Answer (score 0):

You can be use from `row_number()` in `postgresql`. then sum fields that row numbers is one (for example).